# Rollback master branch using only pull requests (no reset, no push directly to master etc.)

Tags: git, github, rollback, git-reset

Our repo is locked down to allow only code reviewed Pull Requests to modify master (be merged to master).

We had to rollback a deployment of master branch that had a bug. I need to make the GitHub repo, master branch, be equivalent code to the commit to which we rolled back. However I cannot simply do a `git reset ---hard` on my local repo, and then push that new master to the github repo.

I have to do it using only Pull Requests.

Answer (score 3):

When you can't resort to rewrite your repo history, you can always `revert` commits.

Reverting a given commit does **not** alter history, it creates a new commit on the currently checked-out tip of the tree, containing the exact opposite of changes introduced in the original faulty commit to be reverted.

After creating this commit, push it on top of your remote master (or alternatively, push it on a new branch created from `master` and make a PR between it and master) and *voilà*!

Check [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) if needed.

Comment: Note also that you can amend `revert` commits. And yes, `Revert "Revert "Revert "Revert "Some commit""""` happens.

Comment: @o11c Must be said, this is true. Better have a good commit message policy in your team if you want to know which is which in these cases...